# Cannot find grldr in all devices

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, wubi, grub2

I'm running wubi on XP machine. Started out originally with 8.04, and gradually upgraded to 10.04. Recently, I was creating linux bootable USB drive, and put it in my system to see if it would work. After booting the LiveOS, and rebooting my machine, I know get the error `Cannot find grldr in all devices` when booting Ubuntu.
I don't know what grldr is, but I assume it is the GRUB Loader.

Did booting the LiveOS screw with my MBR perhaps?

How can I fix this, and if not, is it possible to reinstall wubi, without losing *anything* of what I have now?

Answer (score 0):

This is my problem too and it is completely new for me. Reinstalling doesn't make any sense, the problem remains.

When I installed Ubuntu on my external hard drive I got the same problem, but then I copied wubildr wubildr.mbr to my external hard drive and then Ubuntu worked. But with these files on my local hard drive, the problem persists.